# Georeferencing to UTM coordinates from MATLAB script gives an offset in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, georeferencing, matlab

I have a MATLAB script to georeference a matrix to UTM coordinates, that can be imported into QGIS. The script (1) works as intended, although with a slight offset from the true position when I import it. I know the UTM zone is correct, and I know the limits of the georeferencing grid and size are correct because I set this in an earlier script. I've checked the EPSG code with the GIS too.
I also have a similar script (2) for doing the same but in WGS84 Lat-Lon coordinates, which works fine without the offset. Any clues as to what might be causing the offsets in the UTM data, or better ways to do this?

Thanks!

UTM script (1):
[image]

WGS84 script(2):
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: UTM extents don't follow the longitude/latitude lines which are curved except for the central meridian and the equator. If it's tipped a bit compared to the WGS84-built one, that's likely the reason.